# Flying Saucer not rendering PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I am converting HTML form to PDF with Flying-Saucer but the PDF output doesn't have all the formatting (CSS & Bootstrap Applied). It is also clipping the side of the page.

> The form rendered in HTML looks like:

[image: HTML]

> But the PDF comes out as:

[image: PDF]

From the above it looks like its getting the panes with rounded edges, but no colors, so I presume its lacking the css.

The HTML relies on a external css file, boostrap css, and bootswatch css theme. So the css references in the html are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/assessment.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The java to generate the PDF using Flying Saucer is:

```
    @Qualifier("templateEngine")
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
public void createPdf(String templateName, Map map) throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(templateName, "The templateName can not be null");
    Context ctx = new Context();
    if (map != null) {
        Iterator itMap = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itMap.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) itMap.next();
            ctx.setVariable(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    //String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String fileName = "Assessment.pdf";
    try {
        final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
        os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.getSharedContext().getUserAgentCallback().setBaseURL("/resources/static/css");
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os, false);
        renderer.finishPDF();
```

I am not entirely sure that this path is correct:

```
renderer.getSharedContext().getUserAgentCallback().setBaseURL("/resources/static/css");
```

Finally the project structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: What does the pdf look like if you use iText 7 + pdfHTML?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I'm not sure if we already support check boxes, but I'm sure it's on the roadmap. If we do already support them, then please ask someone to update the FAQ entry [Can I convert an HTML form to a PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/can-i-convert-html-form-pdf)

Comment: Is that IText7 Community? Is it in Maven repo? I only see Core in Maven which looks like the commercial one? (Using Gradle) Is it this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/root and this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf ?

Comment: Core and Community are exactly the same code-wise. The only difference is the license.

Comment: Thanks. Are those links correct?

Comment: Thanks. So is t root and html2pdf that I need?

Comment: @AlGrant did you end up solving this? I too have just started rendering HTML with Boostrap CSS to PDFs via Flying Saucer and I'm also seeing the clipping on the right hand edge.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using Bootstrap 4.x. It seems you are using Bootstrap 4 as well:

```
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

My "clipped on right" problem went away when I switched to Bootstrap 3.x.

Most likely cause:

Flying Saucer does not support 'Flex'. Bootstrap 4.x uses Flex. Bootstrap 3 does not.

For me at least, everything worked perfectly when converting HTML to PDF when I switched to Bootstrap 3.x.